# Find the smallest number greater than "n" with the same digit sum as "n"

Tags: python, performance, time-limit-exceeded, timeout

Here is my code:

```
def func(n):
    sum_digits_n = 0
    for i in str(n):
        sum_digits_n+=int(i)

    num = n+1

    while True:
        s = 0
        for i in str(num):
            s+=int(i)
        if s==sum_digits_n:
            return num
            break
        else:
            num += 1
```

It works for small to moderate sized `n`. But it takes forever to run with big values of `n`. How can I optimize it?

---

For example, let's check the run times for different sized inputs:

```
import time
inputs = [7,70,700,7000,70000,700000,7000000,70000000]
for i in inputs:
    t = time.time()
    ans = func(i)
    print('Input: {}. Ans: {}. Time taken: {}s\n'.format(i, ans, time.time()-t))
```

[image]

As you can see, even with a not-so-huge input as 70 million, the code takes ~1.5 mins to run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to come up with a trickier algorithm here rather than doing a brute force approach.

Let's try to think about a couple of cases here.

1. `123`, its sum of digits is `6`. If we decrease `3` by `1`, then we'll have to increase `2` by `1` (as you're trying to get the least larger element) `->` `132`
2. `1293`, sum of digits is `15`. If we decrement `3` and increment `2` (`9` is already a maximum digit so we cannot increment it) then we'll get `1392`. But is it really the least greater value? Well, no, `1329` is. So, what we should do it increment `2`, substitute `9` with `3` and decrement `3` (as `2` was just incremented). `9` must go to the end to minimise the value as much as possible.
3. `129993` - here we have a similar case as #2. The only difference is that the full `999` must go to the end `->` `132999`.
4. `12920` - another interesting case. But again, find the first non-zero digit from the left, then if `9`s are its immediate neighbours move them to  the end, decrement `2` and put `0` before it -> `13019`.

Hopefully, based on examples above it's clear which steps have to be implemented (we move from right to left):

- Find the rightmost digit that can be decremented. So, `0` cannot be such a digit as it's minimal already. If such digit doesn't exist then there's no solution. Decrement it.
- Find the closest digit to the left of the digit from step `1` that can be incremented. So, `9` cannot be such a digit as it's maximum already. If there's no such digit then just prepend `0` to the start of the current number. Increment the digit.
- Now, sort all the digits after the digit from step `2` in ascending order.
- You have a solution now!

**UPDATE**

As a bonus, a quick implementation of the approach in **Python**. I'll leave it up to you to improve this solution (if possible :) )

```
def solve(n):
    size = len(n)

    trailing_zeros = list()
    first_nines = list()

    i = size - 1
    while i >= 0:
        if int(n[i]) != 0:
            break
        trailing_zeros.append(n[i])
        i -= 1

    if i < 0:
        print ("No solution!")
        return

    first_non_zero_digit = int(n[i])
    i -= 1
    while i >= 0:
        if int(n[i]) != 9:
            break
        first_nines.append(n[i])
        i -= 1

    if i < 0:
        remaining = '1'
    else:
        increased_digit = int(n[i]) + 1
        remaining = ''.join(n[:i]) + str(increased_digit)

    print(remaining + ''.join(trailing_zeros) + str(first_non_zero_digit - 1) + ''.join(first_nines))
```

Comment: I new I was missing something. Thanks for finding it!

Comment: @OscarSmith I also added a quick implementation of the approach, Maybe it will be also useful :)

Answer (score 3):

This is a case where your algorithm needs help. There are 3 cases to consider: only 1 nonzero digit, 1 less than a power of 10, and everything else.

1. `a*10^n` goes to `10^(n+1)+(a-1)`
2. `10^n - 1` goes to `10^n + 10^n - 10^(n-1)`
3. Otherwise, increase the 2nd least significant non-zero by 1, and decrease the last nonzero by 1.

This algorithm will run in linear time to the number of digits in `n` (as opposed to yours which is exponential).

Comment: your algorithm is not sufficient. 101 shall be 110 not 200.

Answer (score 1):

## Algorithm

Yout code searches all numbers and test for the sum. That is inefficient.

The result consists from left to right of

- 0 or more digits from the original input
- exactly one digit that is incremented (could be a leading zero incremented to one)
- the minimal representation of the remaining sum r filling the remaining digits which is from right to left

  - `r//9` '9's
  - one digit `r%9` (only if greater 0)
  - 0 or more leading '0's to fill the gap